# Retrieving selected data from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm developing a small web app for uni and one of the requirements is that it has to have a list, with data from a database, that can be sorted by clicking on a certain category and then only the items from that category will get displayed.
I've managed to retrieve the data from the database into a table on the website, however, the drop down menu to select which category you would like to look at, doesn't work. Meaning that it displays all the items from the database no matter what. I do not receive any errors and really have no idea how I could solve this problem.
Hopefully someone will be able to help me with this. 
Code for the function which is supposed to only display items from that category:

```
//Get ItemEntity objects from the database and return them in an array.
function GetItemByCategory($category) {
    // require 'dbconnect.php';

    //Open connection and Select database.     
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login") or die(mysqli_error);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category LIKE '$category'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $itemArray = array();

    //Get data from database.
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $name = $row[1];
        $category = $row[2];
        $place = $row[3];
        $date = $row[4];
        $description = $row[5];
        $image = $row[6];

        //Create item objects and store them in an array.
        $item = new ItemEntity(-1, $name, $category, $place, $date, $description, $image);
        array_push($itemArray, $item);
    }
    //Close connection and return result
    mysqli_close($con);
    return $itemArray;
}

}
```

I'm still quite new to this so it might be a simple fix but like I said, I'm lost so that's why I've reached out.
Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more code from me.

//edit
HTML form which displays the data. If anything else is needed, let me know. Thanks for your help.

```
function CreateItemTables($categories)
    {
        $itemModel = new ItemModel();
        $itemArray = $itemModel->GetItemByCategory($categories);
        $result = "";

        // Generate an item table for each item entity in the array
        foreach ($itemArray as $key => $item) {
            $result = $result . "<table class = 'itemTable'>
                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan='6' width = '150px' ><img runat = 'server' src = '$item->image'/></th>
                                    <th width = '75px' >Name: </th>
                                    <td>$item->name</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Category: </th>
                                    <td>$item->category</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Place: </th>
                                    <td>$item->place</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Date: </th>
                                    <td>$item->date</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan='2' >$item->description</td>
                                </tr>


                                </table>";
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

//edit 2 Whole ItemController class

```
<?php

require ("Model/ItemModel.php");

/**
* Contains non-db related functions for the Item page
*/
class ItemController
{

    function CreateItemDropdownList()
    {
        $itemModel = new ItemModel();
        $result = "<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
                    Please select a category: <select name = 'types' >
                    <option value = '%' >ALL</option>".$this->CreateOptionValues($itemModel->GetCategories())."
                    </select>
                    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search'  /></form>";

                return $result;
    }
    function CreateOptionValues(array $valueArray)
    {
        $result = "";

        foreach ($valueArray as $value) 
        {
            $result = $result . "<option value ='$value'>$value</option>";
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function CreateItemTables($categories)
    {
        $itemModel = new ItemModel();
        $itemArray = $itemModel->GetItemByCategory($categories);
        $result = "";

        // Generate an item table for each item entity in the array
        foreach ($itemArray as $key => $item) {
            $result = $result . "<table class = 'itemTable'>
                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan='6' width = '150px' ><img runat = 'server' src = '$item->image'/></th>
                                    <th width = '75px' >Name: </th>
                                    <td>$item->name</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Category: </th>
                                    <td>$item->category</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Place: </th>
                                    <td>$item->place</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Date: </th>
                                    <td>$item->date</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan='2' >$item->description</td>
                                </tr>


                                </table>";
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't really know how your db looks like but what if you change "category LIKE '$category'" to "category='$category'" ?

Comment: Try to do some self-debug. Make sure your function received the given category, since your function looks okay.

Comment: Debug your code. Find what query are you getting in $query variable by printing the variable.

Comment: What are you passing to the function in `$category` Show the HTML `<form>` and the code that gets that and loads `$category`

Comment: Do you really mean to use `LIKE` if you have a specific `category` use `category = '$category'`

Comment: @DeadMaster Nothing is being displayed whether I choose the category or not when I do that. I'll edit and add the code for the form now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //changed like to = more accurate 
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category = '$category'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $itemArray = array();

    //Get data from database.
//note this
$i=0;   

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        //gave then a record number so you get the right data
        $name = $row[$i];
        $category = $row[$i];
        $place = $row[$i];
        $date = $row[$i];
        $description = $row[$i];
        $image = $row[$i];
$item = new ItemEntity($i, $name, $category, $place, $date, $description, $image);
$i++;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, nothing is being displayed if I decide to use your loop. I assume that this means that there is a problem with the html form method which gets this data? (posted above)

Comment: if you use row['1'] row['2'] you will only get one set of data and even from different rows you can't use it that way. before getting to html should check the php first. dumb or echo the results do the same with the array then show us

Comment: I'm not sure if I've done it correctly but I echoed the query from GetItemByCategory. This is what happens: SELECT * FROM items WHERE category LIKE '%'
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Coursework2\Controller\ItemController.php on line 40 The code for the controller has been supplied above. If this is what I was supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: var_dump($result); gives me this when I run it: object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(3) ["type"]=> int(0) } 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Coursework2\Controller\ItemController.php on line 40 Hopefully that helps.

Comment: echo works like this  echo $name; also echo the mysql_error() like this echo mysqli_error(); when i first learned php i echo my variables and stuff out at every step then i can see where i go wrong then after everything works i deleted the echo's otherwise you don't know where you going wrong

Comment: yes but show your whole controller.php code in the code you showed it doesn't have a for each loop

Comment: Ok, added the whole controller class in the main post.

Comment: maybe it will be quicker to make a new controller2.php

Comment: is the display type html?

Comment: What would I put in controller 2 in that case? I don't remember changing the display type at all.